# Resize an image for a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I have a UIButton with text and an image. I want the image to sit beside the text.

My image is 100x100 px. As a result, when I use...

scaleAspectFit
contentHorizontalAlignment
or imageEdgeInsets

...the image changes size visually, but does not change the size of the 100px frame for the space the image takes up in the button (represented by the grey box). This pushes the text to the side. (image 1)

I can obtain the correct result by messing with the imageEdgeInsets values but only for one device at a time because the size of the button varies with screen size.

Is there a better way to change the size of the image frame directly without using an image with a smaller resolution (which results in vastly reduced image quality)? (image 2)

I have created a visual representation of the desired outcome on photoshop (image 3).

[image: image with UIView scaling/imageInsets, visually correct size but grey frame pushes]

[image: correct size and placement but poor image quality]

[image: desired result (created in photoshop)]

Comment: The best way is to use custom view. The hierarchy will be view-> Image - Label -> UIButton.

Comment: @Zain could you please point me in the right direction to learn about custom views and hierarchies, I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Custom view like below:

1. Add a view in your storyboard
2. Then add cornerRadius to that view
3. Add an imageView and set your desire height and width.
4. Add a label
5. Wrap imageView and Label in a StackView.
6. Add StackView constraits to rootView.
7. Finally add TapGesture to that rootView so that its work like a button.

[image: I have created this one]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get conflicting constraints when I try to make the image smaller than the view. Any ideas?

Comment: add imageview fixed height and width and stackview's vertical and horizontal Constaints to root view . i have added the image in my answer

Comment: I followed these steps and it's 90% there. There is just one problem! Because the stack view contains both an image and text, the text is not horizontally centred when the stack view is centred. In the above image you can see that the 'S' in 'Sign' and the 'e' in 'Google' are both equal distance from the border. This is not the case with my stack view. Instead the googleImage and the 'e' are equal distance from the border because both items are being centred at the same time. It's a minor problem, but if you have a solution to fix this it would be awesome.

Comment: Followup to previous comment! I removed the stack view, centred the text and then added a leading constraint to the image from the text. Everyone looks perfect now =]

Comment: give horizontal constraints -6 or -7  to adjust imageanf title centered.i think it would be work fine.